# how to check tab load failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

I need do something on tabs updated, like check if the page load correct, and replace something inside the page. here is my code

```
// background.js

chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    try{
       chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, filename);
    } catch(e) {
       // 1. when I open a new tab
       // 1. Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.
       // 2. when I request a url not arrive-able.
       // 2. Error during tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url 
       //    "data:text/html,chromewebdata". Extension manifest must request 
       //    permission to access this host.

       // but I can't catch these errors, they just appers in background console.  
    }
});
```

I try to executeScript when it upload, but if the current tab is chrome://newtab or chrome error page, I can't do this, but I can't catch the error.

Answer (score 11):

There's no direct way to catch these errors. However, I've just created a method to accomplish the goals:

- Use [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) (with a `d`!).
  This event is fired twice, when the page is initializing (`"loading"`), and when the DOM has loaded (`"complete"`).
- Use [`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: fileName}, fn_callback);`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)
  The second argument has to be an object, containing either `"file"`, or `"code"`. The third argument, a function, is always executed after finishing the script injection.

  Now, the real implementation:
- 1. Execute the content script (using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)).
  2. In the injected content script, define an `onMessage` event.
  3. In the callback function of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, follow these steps:
  4. Use [`var exec_error = setTimeout(onError, 100);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) to defer the execution of your `onError` method. Choose an appropriately small delay (100), and save a reference to this timeout in a variable, `exec_error`.
  5. Use [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, func)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) to send a message to the tab.
  6. In callback function **`func`**, add this logic:

     - Validate the response (is the event not created by another part of the extension?)
     - [`clearTimeout(exec_error)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout)
     - `onSuccess()`
  7. When an error occurs, the `onMessage` event as defined in **2.** will not be injected. Hence, the tab will not respond as expected, and the time-out is not cleared. **As a result, `onError` will be executed**.
     Otherwise, the timeout is cleared, and **`onSuccess` is executed**.

### Code (e.g. [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) script):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // This event fires twice: loading, and complete.
    // If we're loading, terminate function, and wait for "complete"
    if (changeInfo.status === 'loading') return;

    // On error and on success, this happens:
    function onError() {
        console.log('Error injecting the content script!');
    }
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully injected content script!');
    }

    // Execute scripts
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        file: 'test_access.js'
    }, function() {
        // This function always fires *after* the attempt to run the code
        var exec_error = setTimeout(onError, 100);
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, 'Are you there?', function(yes_no) {
            if (yes_no === 'Yes') {
                clearTimeout(exec_error);
                onSuccess();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

### `test_access.js`

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(req, sender, respond) {
   if (req === 'Are you there?') {
       respond('Yes');
   }
});
// Rest of your content script's logic, eg:
alert(location.href);
```

Comment: RobW you are a chrome extension genius!

Comment: @CrisStringfellow Thanks. I've updated the answer to use the `sendMessage`/`onMessage` methods instead of `sendRequest`/`onRequest`, because the latter has been deprecated in favour of the former since Chrome 20.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load scripts via extensions for pages having url like `chrome://`. You can however [override](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html) some pages completely, but not in the same extension in which you are loading scripts to some other pages.